# Can't verify IAP receipt with service account, "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation"

Tags: in-app-purchase, permission-denied, service-accounts, receipt-validation, in-app-subscription

Created service account within Google Cloud Console ( https://console.cloud.google.com)

The service account has "owner" role.

Went to https://play.google.com/apps/publish and added this account ( using the email within the json file ) with "Administrator" access level

Made sure it included  "View financial reports" option.

Trying to validate a receipt I always get this response:

`{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "androidpublisher",
            "reason": "permissionDenied",
            "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
        }],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
    }
}`

What am I missing?

I'm using this code:
https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some delay to make permissions effective for service accounts, we left office on Friday and it wasn't working, when we got here on Monday it worked without any change.